# how to add dynamic ng-repeat in page onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create dynamic ng-reapet and push the array element on click event:

my controler code is

```
$scope.AddlistItem = function (index) {
$scope.selecttaglist($scope.tag);
};

$scope.selecttaglist = function (tag) {
 //var i=$scope.selectedTags.length;
    angular.forEach($scope.selectedTags,function(tag,index){
        console.log(tag.name);
        $scope.selectedTagslist.push(tag);
})
```

And View Code:

```
<ul id="boxElement" ><li ng-repeat="tag in selectedTagslist" ng-controller="ItemController" ng-bind="tag.name" ></li></ul>
```

Html Code

```
<div class="AddButtn" id="aDD{{item.name}}" ng-controller="ItemController" ng-click="AddlistItem()" ></div>
```

problem is that when i clicking on link. array element are pushing on all ng-reapet element.i want array  will be push only on clicked element container. iam not sure my approach is write or wrong for doing this. i am new in angularjs. anyone can help on this.

Answer (score 1):

If the model for `ng-repeat` is the same then you need different approach as model drives the view so i.e. you will need more than one

```
<ul id="boxElement" ><li ng-repeat="tag in selectedTagslist" ng-controller="ItemController" ng-bind="tag.name" ></li></ul>
<ul id="boxElement" ><li ng-repeat="tag in selectedTagslist2" ng-controller="ItemController" ng-bind="tag.name" ></li></ul>
```

with a copy of the first element - `angular.copy` otherwise the object will be connected by reference and the effect will be same

hope that makes sense